# Cant install pycrypto module in 3.5.2 version

Tags: python, module, python-3.5, pycrypto

yesterday, for HOURS, I've been trying to install pycrypto on python 3.7 version. I installed build tools thing, restarted my computer - no success. I decided to uninstall python and install 3.5.2 version, and guess what? I actually managed to install it somehow. now I'm trying to install pycrypto again and I'm getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is the result of a source package that requires compilation using a C(++) compiler.

setuptools is unable to find your vcvarsall.bat (which configures Visual Studio). You'll want to refer to the python documentation on [Binary extensions for Windows](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-binary-extensions/#building-binary-extensions)

You may also find Microsoft's explanation [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) useful.

I suggest you use the the information above to build the extensions from source, but if that isn't in the cards (it can take time to configure), then you can search for pre-built binaries eg these: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

I have not use those binaries, and generally do not suggest installing binaries when you can compile from source -- particularly with things like crypto.

Comment: could you provide me a example how to compile that source?